# Building a C/C++ Library: How to include symbols from multiple .h files?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, libraries

I am trying to build a static library in C & C++. I want the user application to utilize the functions in api.cpp, while api.cpp references other code in the library. My user-application will have a 'my-lib.h' to use for its include...but the problem is how does the user-app use the structs and functions in the libraries .h file without having to redefine them?

```
library/
    src/
        api.cpp // file that i would like the user-applications to utilize
        ... all other .cpp and .c code that api.cpp references
    include/
        all .h files for the code in src/ 

user-app/
    main.cpp
    my-lib.h
    my-lib.a
```

Here is my-lib.h:

```
#ifndef MY_LIB_H
#define MY_LIB_H
// functions to be exposed for user applications. 

void hello_world();
int initialize_sx1262_from_file();
int transmit_num_packets(sx1262& p_chip, test_config& p_tc, bool echoing);


#endif
```

And here is api.cpp that resides in src/ :

```
...

#include "ini.h"

#include "sx1262.h"
#include "sx126x.h"

void hello_world(){

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

}


int initialize_sx1262_from_file(){
   // do stuff
}



int transmit_num_packets(sx1262& p_chip, test_config& p_tc, bool echoing ){
   // do stuff
}

...
```

I would like to utilize the symbols in "sx1262.h" in my user-application without having to redefine them and maintaining the purpose of a unified library without the user-application having to include so many files.

Comment: You should not define functions or variables in the header. Instead have a `cpp` file that defines them and only declare them in the header. If you are mixing 2 languages `c++` and `c ` you will have to deal with name mangling and other issues: [https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)

Comment: Why not put `#include "sx1262.h"` in `my-lib.h`? That seems like the obvious thing to do.

Comment: @john I have tried doing as you suggested but that does not work unless you edit the file to specify the location of the library...I suppose if I write this as a shared library so that it is standardized for user-applications on this device it would be more feasible

Comment: The problem is unclear. Please show *specific* error messages or other undesirable effects you encounter. Generally you just write your library in exactly the same way the other 100,000,000 C++ libraries are written. Location of the library is a matter of packaging it for a specific OS. Static vs shared have nothing to do with it.

Comment: @engineerman That is normal, when users include header files from third parties it's normal that they have to specify the location of those header files using whatever compiler options are needed for their compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I can include the other .h files by pointing g++ to my library using the -I flag when compiling my user-application.